# ffmpeg Multiple Audio Language and Soft- Subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a movie, using ffmpeg, from Movie.mkv to Movie.m4v. The Movie has 2 Languages and 1 subtitle stream.

Using

```
ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mkv outputmovie.m4v
```

the result is just one audio and no soft subtitles.

What should I use to keep both languages and the subtitle (to toggle On-off on streaming box)

Thank you.

The ffprobe from movie is:

```
ffprobe version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'DasParfum.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libmakemkv v1.9.9 (1.3.3/1.4.4) darwin(x86-release)
    creation_time   : 2016-01-22 21:40:23
  Duration: 02:21:28.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5414 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 395.200000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 395.200000, end 633.880000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 633.880000, end 816.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 816.400000, end 1031.680000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1031.680000, end 1294.280000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1294.280000, end 1593.800000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1593.800000, end 1928.680000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 1928.680000, end 2262.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 2262.000000, end 2598.960000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 2598.960000, end 2845.960000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 2845.960000, end 3193.320000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3193.320000, end 3427.320000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3427.320000, end 3652.480000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3652.480000, end 3966.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 3966.560000, end 4235.920000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 4235.920000, end 4531.280000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4531.280000, end 4796.480000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 4796.480000, end 5003.960000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 5003.960000, end 5383.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 5383.040000, end 5708.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 5708.040000, end 5943.080000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 5943.080000, end 6212.960000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 6212.960000, end 6488.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 6488.560000, end 6734.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0:24: start 6734.000000, end 6951.880000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0:25: start 6951.880000, end 7214.480000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0:26: start 7214.480000, end 7466.680000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0:27: start 7466.680000, end 7756.840000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Chapter #0:28: start 7756.840000, end 7935.200000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 29
    Chapter #0:29: start 7935.200000, end 8488.440000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 30
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 4572420
      DURATION-eng    : 02:21:28.440000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 212211
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 4851589546
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0100E0
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.9.9 darwin(x86-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-22 21:40:23
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:1(ger): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 448000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:21:28.416000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 265263
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 475351296
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0180BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.9.9 darwin(x86-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-22 21:40:23
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 384000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:21:28.416000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 265263
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 407443968
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0182BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.9.9 darwin(x86-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-22 21:40:23
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:3(ger): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x576 (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2188
      DURATION-eng    : 02:11:22.676977777
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 871
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2156572
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0120BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.9.9 darwin(x86-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-22 21:40:23
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:4(ger): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x576
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2079
      DURATION-eng    : 02:10:36.918400000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 839
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2037440
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0122BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.9.9 darwin(x86-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-22 21:40:23
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mkv -c copy -map 0 outputmovie.m4v
```

Depending on the subtitle format, they may not get copied over. In which case,

```
ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mkv -c copy -c:s mov_text -map 0 outputmovie.m4v
```

**Edit**: Once you have a text-based subtitle format like SRT or ASS, you can use

```
ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mkv -i subtitle.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 outputmovie.m4v
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but they dont work ! In First one I become error: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters : invalid argument. And for second i become:Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:3 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height !!

Comment: Paste the readout of `ffprobe inputmovie.mkv` into your question.

Comment: Your subtitles are image-based and need to be converted to a text-based format like SRT. Once done, you can use the revised 2nd command. Use [Subtitle Edit](http://www.videohelp.com/software/Subtitle-Edit) to import from MKV.

Comment: i try it to do with 3 code (after the srt was exported - or downloaded) and i become again error message: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Comment: Paste the readout of ffprobe srt into your question.

Comment: that's the solution: "Edit: Once you have a text-based subtitle format like SRT or ASS, you can use": ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mkv -i subtitle.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 outputmovie.m4v

Comment: now i do it with h265 and it is work; for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i $i -map 0 \
-c:v libx265 \
-preset medium -x265-params crf=20:\
qcomp=0.7:\
ctu=32:\
max-tu-size=16:\
aq-mode=1:\
aq-strength=1.0:\
qg-size=16:\
psy-rd=0.7:\
psy-rdoq=5.0:\
rdoq-level=1:\
merange=50:\
sao=0:\
rect=0:\
amp=0:\
deblock=-2\\:-2 \
-tag:v hvc1 -vsync 2 \
-c:a libfdk_aac \
-cutoff 18000 \
-profile:a aac_he \
-b:a 128k \
-c:s mov_text \
$i.mp4; done

Answer (score 0):

I thin [MKVtoolnix](http://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVtoolnix) is better and can help you get the result that you want.

`MKVtoolnix` is a set of tools to **create**, **alter**, **split**, **join** and **inspect** Matroska files(mkv). Use MKVCleaver or gMKVExtractGUI to extract/demultiplex mkv video and audio files.

**Supported operating systems:** Windows - Mac OS - Linux

**Screenshot :**

[image: MKVtoolnix Version:8.8.0]

Comment: hm i write i need output in m4v and this tool can just mkv output ??

Comment: you can extract or add subtitle from/to mkv videos with it and many other things like extracting or creating chapters, extracting audio separately in a few seconds... try it and you'll see